# How to replace all lines using regex or similar for adding text?

Tags: regex, notepad++, str-replace

I have a text file with:

```
"C:\User\EDITED_FirstFile.txt"
"C:\User\EDITED_Randomfile2.txt"
"C:\User\EDITED_Anotherfile1.txt"
```

I want to change these files so they are like this at the end:

```
"C:\User\EDITED_FirstFile.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPFirstFile.txt"
"C:\User\EDITED_Randomfile2.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPRandomfile2.txt"
"C:\User\EDITED_Anotherfile1.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPAnotherfile1.txt"
```

So that it automatically enters the first file into C:\User\EDITED_TMP*.txt like above. How would I be able to do this (regex?)?

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the replies. Thea actual file is really lengthy (sideways, not in lines) and above was just a portion so it would really look something more like

```
"C:\User\EDITED_FirstFile.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPFirstFile.txt ...some random text.... C:\User\123_FirstFile.txt randomtext " etc. etc.
"C:\User\EDITED_Randomfile2.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPRandomfile2.txt ...some random text.... C:\User\123_Randomfile2.txt randomtext " etc. etc.
"C:\User\EDITED_Anotherfile1.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPAnotherfile1.txt ...some random text.... C:\User\123_Anotherfile1.txt randomtext " etc. etc.
```

Comment: More info is needed, what language do you want this done? PHP could do it

Comment: Please share the regex you tried and what the problem was with it.

Comment: PHP is fine and I'm not sure if regex is able because I'm not familiar with it

Comment: did you want to change files or it's contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
^"([^_]*\_)([^"]*)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pC6jE1)

Your php code would be,

```
<?php
$string = <<<EOT
"C:\User\EDITED_FirstFile.txt"
"C:\User\EDITED_Randomfile2.txt"
"C:\User\EDITED_Anotherfile1.txt"
EOT;
$pattern = '/(?m)^"([^_]*\_)([^"]*)/i';
$replacement = "\"$1$2 abhsbahsbhabhabsha $1TMP$2";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
"C:\User\EDITED_FirstFile.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPFirstFile.txt"
"C:\User\EDITED_Randomfile2.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPRandomfile2.txt"
"C:\User\EDITED_Anotherfile1.txt abhsbahsbhabhabsha C:\User\EDITED_TMPAnotherfile1.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think this is the best way but the actual length of my file is long (sideways, not line count) and but I have edited my top comment!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way of doing it with PHP:

```
$lines = file('test.txt'); //Read test.txt
foreach($lines as $line) { //Loop through all the lines
    $line = trim($line, "\n"); //Remove newline characters
    $final = $line . ' abhsbahsbhabhabsha ' . str_replace('EDITED_', 'EDITED_TMP', $line . "\n"; //Replace what's needed and add a new line
    file_put_contents('test2.txt', $final, FILE_APPEND); //Do whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think this is a good way but the actual length of my file is long (not length in lines but actual line lengths) and i'm not sure how possible it would be to change for it! I have edited my top post with extra info

Comment: So what you added to the post is the original file or your desired output?

Comment: So how would you like it to look afterward because what you posted in the begining was COMPLETELY diffrent?

Answer (score 0):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Find what: `^"(.*)"$`
Replace with: `"$1 abhsbahsbhabhabsha $1"`

Use grouping feature of regex pattern that is captured by enclosing it inside parenthesis `()` and get the matched group using `$1`.

Snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think this is the best way but the actual length of my file is long (sideways, not line count) and but I have edited my top comment with more info!

Comment: It's not clear to me. can you modify your regex as per your need.